# Back4App - Pointer to an unsaved object. (Code: 106, Version: 1.19.1)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

I have next structure:

1. `Invoice` class.
2. `Invoice` contains `Array` of `InvoiceEmployee` pointers
3. `InvoiceEmployee` contains array of `InvoiceItem` objects

```
for employeeDataSet in someDataSet { 

for viewModelData in someDataSet { 
let pfInvoiceItem = PFObject(className: "InvoiceItem")
pfInvoiceItem.setValue(viewModelData.customerRate, forKey: "customerRate")
pfInvoiceItem.setValue(viewModelData.customerHours, forKey: "customerHours")
pfInvoiceItem.setValue(viewModelData.total, forKey: "total")
invoiceItems.append(pfInvoiceItem)
}


let pfInvoiceEmployee = PFObject(className: "InvoiceEmployee")
pfInvoiceEmployee.setValue(employeeDataSet.username, forKey: "username")
pfInvoiceEmployee.setValue(employeeDataSet.projectEmployee, forKey: "projectEmployee")
pfInvoiceEmployee.setValue(invoiceItems, forKey: "invoiceItems")
```

I am getting this error

```
Pointer to an unsaved object. (Code: 106, Version: 1.19.1)
```

On this save action:

```
func createInvoice(with invoice: Invoice, completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, NSError>) -> ()) {
        
        guard let payPeriod = invoice.payPeriod?.getPFPayPeriod(),
              let project = invoice.project?.getPFProject() else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "OURTEAM", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Save invoice failure"])
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        
        let parseObject = PFObject(className:"Invoice")
        parseObject["project"] = project
        parseObject["payPeriod"] = payPeriod
        parseObject["title"] = "Some"
        parseObject["total"] = invoice.total
        parseObject["invoiceEmployees"] = invoice.getPFInvoiceEmployees()

        parseObject.saveInBackground {
          (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
          if (success) {
            completion(.success(true))
          } else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "OURTEAM", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Create invoice failure"])
            completion(.failure(error))
          }
        }
    }
```

But when I am looking to admin panel I can see that all record are saved properly. Meaning that `InvoiceItem` records got all objectIds and needed columns are set with values. The same fo `InvoiceEmployee` records and Invoice record in databse.

Also `parseObject.saveInBackground` returns success.

One thing to know that I have not saved `InvoiceItem` and `InvoiceEmployee` previously before I saved `Invoice`.

Usually I work with joint class and there is no such issue as I can save objects separately. Now  I wold like to save invoice on demand (when all local records are fulfilled by user).

I guess could be a solution to create `Invoice` first of all and then add all needed data to it. But it means that I need to wait for accomplishment all callbacks related to adding employees and their items to the `Invoice` and if user cancel creation of invoice then I need to remove a record in database, which is a bit overloaded flow.

Comment: if saveInBackground returns success, where are you getting the error then?

Comment: I guess the problem happens because it is an array (and not a pointer or relation). In this case I believe you will have to first save the pointers and then save the main object. Another option could be sending all the data to a cloud code function to perform the operation.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. it is not callback error it is a log message. Looks like back4app handles creating pointers if needed somehow. I checked tables and all records were created all relationship were assigned. Maybe this is just a warning and I don't need to do anything with it.